# How to version control with Git whilst using composer?

Tags: drush, 9, composer, version-control

So I've been going through the steep learning curve from D7 to D9.

I like to use git for deployment and version control. I'm new to composer as I only know Drupal and it was never used.

I've developed the whole website using composer and drush on my local machine. Namely `composer require drupal/[modulename] && drush en [modulename]-y`

I moved the example.gitignore file from the web directory to the base as .gitignore. Updated the paths to reflect the move.

Without the comments it contain this:

```
web/core
vendor
web/sites/*/settings*.php
web/sites/*/services*.yml
web/sites/*/files
web/sites/*/files/private
web/sites/simpletest
```

Having completed the website I ran the usual commands on my local copy.

```
drush cex && git add . && git commit -m "Some commit message" && git push origin master
```

On my server I pulled the code down and imported my database. I read that I then run `composer install`.

After that, my contrib module patches were overridden? I'm guessing that the `composer install` command grabs fresh copies of everything?

What then is the correct method?

Comment: You wouldn't run composer in production. You would either push the entire artifact to the cloud, or have a continuous integration service build the code and deploy for you.

Comment: So I would remove web/core & vendor from my .gitignore. Never use composer in production. Then I'm good to go?

Comment: You also apply patches via Composer. Some people do run composer install on prod. What Kevin talks about are advanced deployment strategies.

Comment: http://www.yuseferi.com/en/blog/How-apply-patches-Drupal-8-Composer

Comment: This tutorial I wrote on Composer may help: https://www.morpht.com/blog/drupal-and-composer-part-1-understanding-composer. 
It's slightly outdated (I don't work at the place to be able to update it), but mostly still relevant, and written for people new to using Composer with Drupal.

Comment: Thanks for the upgrade to you all and the posts. My take away is that the Drupal site should be built and updated with composer locally. Commit everything but user content and settings.php. Then in production pull down the complete codebase. Albeit it technically possible to run "composer install" on a production server to sync the contributed code, with the help of the "cweagans/composer-patches.". Most commonly, this isn't done on a live server and is arguably a preference. Is that a fair interpretation?